# css style text with no tag inside class

Tags: html, css

I am on a `wordpress` website of a client where I have to remove text they added by mistake under their logo . They use `Outreach Pro` wordpress theme and I cannot find in the theme where to remove the text in the header so I am going with custom css .

The format however with the text for the element is

```html
<div class="title-area">
  <h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="...">TEXT I WANT </a></h1>TEXT TO REMOVE
</div>
```

where `TEXT TO REMOVE` is outside of the `h1` tag , so how can I make its display `none` without including the `h1` tag ?
Thank you in advance

Comment: you can add `display: none` to `site-title` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like an option, you can make your container flex with row layout and move text content you want to remove to the right; And text outside block will be cropped.
Also you can move text to hide war away from view port by `text-indent: 1000%;`, see Code Snippet with comments:

```css
.title-area {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; /* make text in one line */
  text-indent: 1000%; /* move text to remove far away */
}

.title-area .site-title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-indent: 0; /* move site title to the beginning */
}
```

```html
<div class="title-area">
  <h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="...">TEXT I WANT </a></h1>TEXT TO REMOVE
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `font-size` to zero, and re-set if for the children:

```css
.title-area { font-size: 0; }

.title-area h1 { font-size: 32px; }
```

```html
<div class="title-area">
  <h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="...">TEXT I WANT </a></h1>TEXT TO REMOVE
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rules get overridden in css

```css
.title-area
{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.site-title
{
    visibility:visible;
};
```

```html
<div class="title-area">
  <h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="...">TEXT I WANT </a></h1>TEXT TO REMOVE
</div>
```

Comment: This way the invisible text still consumes space.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using js or css. I will show only the js solution for it.

**JS Version**

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".title-area > *");
document.querySelector(".title-area").innerHTML = el.outerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="title-area">
  <h1 class="site-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="...">TEXT I WANT </a></h1>
  TEXT TO REMOVE 
</div>
```